# iphone:Error while setting the text in table row cell in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone

when i use this code it shows an error

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

// Set up the cell
SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Animal *animal = (Animal *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell setText:animal.name];
return cell;
```

}

when i use  [cell setText:animal.name] it shows an error like 'setText' is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[cell.textLabel setText:animal.name];`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah..use the following line instead..

```
    [cell.textLabel setText:(NSString *)]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `UITableViewCell` `text` property *was* deprecated as of iOS 3.0--see the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text).  The `UILabel` that is used for the text label is exposed as the `textLabel` property of a `UITableView` instance. Try this instead:

`cell.textLabel.text = animal.name;`